# Assigning Task when opportunity it closed won

Tags: apex, opportunity, code

I have this code that creates a task when opportunity is closed won, however it needs to be assigned to one specific person only.

```
trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update)
{ 
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(); 
    for (Opportunity Opp : Trigger.new) 
    { 
        if(Opp.StageName == 'Closed Won')
        {
        Task tsk = new Task(whatID = Opp.ID, subject='Follow Up Test Task'); 
        tasks.add(tsk); 
        }
    } 
    insert tasks; 
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an assignment to the `OwnerId` field of the Tasks. Since hard-coding Ids is a bad practice, you may want to store the desired ownership in a Custom Setting that your trigger can access efficiently so that you can maintain this solution in the future.

Note also that your trigger will create a task any time an Opportunity is modified if its stage is Closed Won - *not* exactly once when the Opportunity enters that stage. If the latter behavior is what you want, you'd need to do something like

```
if (opp.StageName == 'Closed Won' && Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName != 'Closed Won') {
```

(That's applicable only to `update`, of course, as `insert` has no `oldMap`).

Comment: Thanks David, I will adjust the code to add that. Yeah I dont want to hard code the Id. I know thats bad practice. And yes its the latter behavior. Only when the opportunity enters closedwon.